# iOS 7 Navigation Bar Back Button Title change upon Language change

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, backbarbuttonitem

When the user change language settings from the app then I want to change the title of the back button to that language.How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this simple approach.

1. Access your device language as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4221416/1307844).
2. Now change your back button title as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9871775/1307844)

Hope that helps.

Comment: You have to figure out the language settings whenever the app starts or enters into background. This is so because if you change language in settings menu, you have to do the app switchin which triggers events for app entering into background or did enter foreground.