# How do I disable the text from the navigation bar back button for every view controller?

Tags: ios

How do I disable the text from the navigation bar back button for every view controller?

I would like the back button to contain just the default "<" icon.

It takes up too much space.

Here is way of doing it, but it seems awkward to have to change every view controller.

[How to change the UINavigationController back button name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871578/how-to-change-the-uinavigationcontroller-back-button-name)

Thank you.

Comment: You could do the same thing but in a navigation controller delegate...

Comment: You will have to subclass `UINavigationController` and use the `- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated` to set the title as given in the link in your question.