# swift 3 IOS - Back button issue

Tags: ios, swift, back-button

I'm trying to go from viewController to Another

my problem is that the back button is showing as "<" and not "< Back"
and i didn't understand why, especially cause i'm able to go from this viewController to another one, and the back button is perfect

do anyone faced the same problem ? and how could i solve it ?

Comment: Did you set a `title` for the first viewcontroller?

Comment: @jalone No i didn't

Comment: @Anthony I wasn't quick enough posting an answer, but I added the code you'd need to set the back button title before you segue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if the title of the new view controller is too long. I think the system in this scenario will favor removing "back" in order to make room for the long title

So try shortening the view controller title

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at code is kinda hard to see, but if you want to workaround it you can take a look at the many other [answers on how to change the back button title](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9871741/691977)

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the text of the back button with the following code...

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    // your segue prep code
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Back"


}
```